# How to redirect specific user agent on specific url to specific url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, googlebot

I have question:

How to create redirect specific user agent on specific url to specific url in htaccess?

e.g

I want to redirect Googlebot when visiting my url:

```
blabla.tld/this-is-url/
```

to

```
 newurl.tld/new-urls/
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in /.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?this-is-url/?$ http://newurl.tld/this-url [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Hello Starkeen, it's not work I tried do you have any methods? thanks a lot

Comment: I try use my browser user agent firefox but not work